# 洩氣 for frustrating?

Tags: mandarin

Google Translate says **frustrating** translates into 洩氣.

CantoDict doesn't list an entry for **frustrating**.

洩氣 doesn't seem very natural, at least from a Cantonese perspective. Is Google Translate correct that this is the proper translation for **frustrating** (for both Cantonese and Mandarin)?

Comment: 洩氣 could be a variation of 泄气. 泄气 is very common, meaning deflating or losing one's heart.

Comment: @dan thanks for the response! could you kindly post as an answer so you can receive credit?

Comment: @dan also could you provide an example sentence? is it a verb or adjective or both? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

洩氣 could be a variation of 泄气.

泄气 is very common. The literal meaning of 泄气 is 'air leakage', but its metaphorical meaning is more common, deflating or losing one's heart.

It can be used as a verb: like 别泄气！meaning 'don't lose your heart!'

Comment: how about you frustrate me -- can you say this with 泄气?

Comment: 泄气 could be a type of frustrating. 泄气 is used when you lose your confidence to do something or you have done something awful that make you lose your confidence for later trying.

Comment: Or you have been discouraged by previous failures, and that kind of ideas.

Comment: Can 泄气 be used as a verb? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

"洩氣(泄气)" is a correct and natural translation of "frustrated", so is "沮丧"(might be slightly better).

For "frustrating", it's "令人泄气"（or "令人沮丧"）.

Comment: could you use 泄气 as a verb, i.e., you frustrate me?

Comment: oops, already promised @dan the points for this question. got you momentarily confused with him. sorry!